# How to refactor directive and change functionality by checking parent scopes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a form with a ton of duplicate functionality in 2 different Controllers, there are slight differences and some major ones in both.

The form sits at the top of a products view controller, but also inside of the products modal controller.

***Test plunker:*** http://plnkr.co/edit/EIW6xoBzQpD26Wwqwwap?p=preview
^ how would you change the string in the `console.log` and the color of the button based on parent scope?

[image]

At first I was going to create a new Controller just for the form, but also the HTML was being duplicated, so decided to put that into a Directive, and just add the Controller code there.

---

**My question now is this:** How would I determine which parent scope the `form-directive` is currently being viewed in? Because depending on the parent scope the functions/methods behave differently.

---

So far I've come up with this:

```
.directive('productForm', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "views/products/productForm.html",
        restrict: "E",
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('controller for productForm');
            console.log($scope);
            console.log($scope.$parent);

            /*
              If parent scope is the page, then this...

              If parent scope is the modal then this instead...
            */
        }
    }
});
```

However it's giving me back `$parent` id's that look like `002` or `00p`. Not very easy to put in if / else statements based on that information.

Have you guys run into this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define 'saveThis' in your controller and pass it to directive using `'&'`

```
  scope: {
      user: '=',
      saveThis : '&'
    },
```

please see demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/sOY8XZtEXLORLmelWssS?p=preview
That gives you more flexibility, in future if you want to use `saveThis` in another controller you can define it inside controller instead adding additional if statement to directive.

Comment: Thanks man! That is cool, and thanks for the working example too... I ended up creating a scopeFactory for my particular problem https://gist.github.com/leongaban/ddf2a5807e4a097900c3, but I definitely see how this can be used too

Answer (score 1):

You could add two way binding variables in the directive scope, this allows you to specify which Ctrl variable gets bound to which directive variable

```
<my-directive shared="scopeVariable">
```

this way you achieve two way binding of the scopeVariable with the shared directive variable

you can learn more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

I advice against this practice and suggest you to isolate common logics and behaviours in services or factories rather than in directives

This is an example of a directive that has isolated scope and shares the 'title' variable with the outer scope.

You could declare this directive this way: 
now inside the directive you can discriminate the location where the directive is defined; just replace the title variable with a location variable and chose better names.

```
.directive('myPane', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      title: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {

    },
    templateUrl: 'my-pane.html'
  };
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I'll check that out, but what do you think of this method too? http://plnkr.co/edit/EIW6xoBzQpD26Wwqwwap?p=preview Basically I'm passing the parent scopes in, or just a string really. Then based on that string inside the child I'm able to change things up :)

Comment: I don't see the example on that page you are talking about, no `shared` directive attribute anywhere. How does that work? Oh is it the section on transclusion? Hmm reading it up...

Comment: if you want to pass a string use the @ character for binding inside the directive